# How can I solve problem of 404 page display?

Tags: go, http-status-code-404

I have the function for the main page, which contains 'if' part for the 404 error page:

```
// Обработчик главной страницы
func home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)  {
    w.Write([]byte("Is it alive?"))
    // Создание страницы 404
    if r.URL.Path != "/" {
        http.NotFound(w, r)
        return
    }
}
```

But when I go to the unable page ('127.0.0.1:4000/nothing' for example), I get back both parts - and message "is it alive?" and "404 page not found":
[image: How it looks like:]
So, what can I do to solve it?

Comment: You're obviously writing "Is it alive?" before handling the not-found scenario. Did you expect something else?

Comment: that is how it is implemented. As long as you write on w, this is transmitted. and if you miss write the response like you did, ie write the body then set headers, weird things happens.

Comment: @Flimzy , I tried this language yesterday. So, I just don't know what can I expect from different actions :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)  {
    // Создание страницы 404
    if r.URL.Path != "/" {
        http.NotFound(w, r)
        return
    }

    w.Write([]byte("Is it alive?"))
}
```